# Why cant I unwrap a UserDefault type string? [Swift 3.0 - Xcode 8]

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type, unwrap

I've stored data sent back by delegate as a user default and I'm trying to prepare it to send in a segue. I am able to send it in a segue, the problem I'm having is the data comes out in the form `"optional[Data]"` I know what optional means, but it doesn't let me unwrap UserDefault like an optional, even though it says it is optional?

Here's the code:

```
 func DataToPass(ArrayName: [String]) {
    print("Check ArrayContent--->",ArrayName)
    var DCollect = [String]()
    var CCollect = [String]()
    DCollect.append(ArrayName[0])
    CCollect.append(ArrayName[1])
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let unwrap = defaults{
        unwrap.set(DCollect, forKey: "DCollect")
        unwrap.set(CCollect, forKey: "CCollect")
    }
}
```

The error is:

> "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'UserDefaults'" on line `if let unwrap = defaults{`

Why can't I unwrap it like this?

Another Attempt:

```
    func DataToPass(ArrayName: [String]) {
        print("Check",ArrayName)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(ArrayName, forKey: "ToCollect")
        }


     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "SegueInfo"{
        let firstController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        if let Tosend = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: 
        "ToCollect") as? String {
        Collect.append(Tosend)
        }
        firstController.AllData = Collect
            }
```

Nothing is appended this way, Tosend is empty?

Comment: That makes no sense. `UserDefaults.standard` is the UserDefaults instance and not an optional.

Comment: The field `standard` in user defaults is declared as `class var standard: UserDefaults { get }`. As you can see, it is not optional, and thus cannot be unwrapped

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard` is not optional. You don't need to unwrap it. The error message tells you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save something to user defaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("It is a string", forKey: "meaningfulIdentifier")
```

To get something out from user defaults:

```
if let anyString = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "meaningfulIdentifier") as? String {
    // Do something with anyString
}
```

***You only need optional binding when you are dealing with getting something out from user defaults. For the data part you need this optional binding, not the `User Defaults` itself.***

Comment: it comes up with unresolved identifier 'standard' when I try save data this way? why might that be?

Comment: Ive added my attempt with this approach above, Ive got the code to run, but nothing gets appended?

Comment: Well, what is the `Type` of your `Collect` var? And how & when are you initializing it?

Comment: Collect is var `Collect = [String]()` and is initialized outside of the function but still within the VC class

Comment: Everything looks fine. Try printing out the `Collect` variable after the `if let Tosend = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"ToCollect") as? String {....}` block and check whether this is empty or not.

Comment: Tried that, its still empty?

Comment: Well, ___you are saving `[String]` but retrieving `String`___. It won't retrieve the value successfully.

Comment: nayem, you legend! That sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

## Why does it tell me that I can't unwrap UserDefaults?

The error message is trying to explain to you that `UserDefaults.standard` is not of an `Optional` type. That means that it is not of type `Optional<UserDefaults>`, which means it can't use the `if-let` statement to unwrap it.

What you want to unwrap is not the `UserDefaults` object which is already provided as a singleton through the `UserDefaults.standard` property.

### What can I unwrap?

What you want to unwrap are the variables you are trying to retrieve.

Those would be the optional types you'll have to deal with. It is `Optional` because it may already exist in the `UserDefaults` or it may not yet exist.

### How do I retrieve a string array that I stored into `UserDefaults`?

Using the key `DCollect`, use the appropriate method (i.e. `stringArray(forKey:)` to retrieve it.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

if let dcollect = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "DCollect") {
   // it already exists; now use the dcollect variable
} else {
   // it does not exist; do something (i.e. add dcollect value?) if it does not exist yet
}
```

### How do I store a string array into `UserDefaults`?

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let value : [String] = ["My", "Very", "Eager", "Pluto"]
standard.set(value, forKey: "DCollect")
```

Comment: it comes up with unresolved identifier 'standard' when I try save data this way? why might that be?

Comment: Accidentally used `standard` instead of the `defaults` constant i defined. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to unwrap `UserDefaults.standard` because you don't need to. It is not an optional, therefore you get error from Xcode.

You can straight add the values to the de UserDefaults like this:

`let u = UserDefaults.standard
u.set(["a", "b", "c"], forKey: "yourKey")`

Comment: Im only trying to unwrap it because when I print it, it comes out like this: `"Optional[data]"` and I want it just as a string, like this `"data"`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget to `import Foundation`

Then try this code

```
func DataToPass(ArrayName: [String]) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(ArrayName, forKey: "ToCollect")
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "SegueInfo"{
        let firstController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        if let Tosend = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "ToCollect") as? [String] {
            Collect += Tosend
        }
        firstController.AllData = Collect
    }
}
```